# Sorting an array of List<string> using linq

Tags: c#, linq

How do I sort an array of `List<string>` by length of string using Linq? The efficiency of execution does not matter.

```
List<string>[] col = new List<string>[]
{
    new List<string>(){"aaa", "bbb"},
    new List<string>(){"a", "b", "d"},
    new List<string>(){"xy","sl","yy","aq"}
}; //Each string in a list of strings of a particular array element has equal length.
```

After sorting should produce

> {"a", "b", "d"}, {"xy","sl","yy","aq"}, {"aaa", "bbb"}

Comment: `col.OrderBy(x => x.Sum(y => y.Length)).ToList();`

Comment: @RomanKoliada That won't give you the correct result.

Comment: @Roman Koliada: The given array itself should be sorted so that the structure is maintained in the original array form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ordered = col.OrderBy(x => x[0].Length).ToList();
```

Try it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNWgWm).

Comment: Thanks for dotnetfiddle.net. Awesome tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort out *existing* `col` list (i.e. in place sorting):

```
col.Sort((left, right) = > left[0].Length.CompareTo(right[0].Length));
```

It's not *Linq*, however.

Answer (score 0):

Order by the length of the first item in each member list:

```
var ordered = col.OrderBy(c => c.First().Length);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aeSnzo)

---

Or if it should be able to handle empty lists and nulls:

```
var ordered = col.OrderBy(c => c.FirstOrDefault()?.Length);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QQzHb7)